# How to change illustrator to not select objects based on centroid

Tags: adobe-illustrator, selections

Many times I make a box around a collection of elements and want to select all the elements *within* that containing box, but not the box itself.

If my selection includes the center of the containing box, it will select the box.

I never had this frustration with CS6 so I think they may have changed it for CC. I think previously it would only select the containing box if it had a fill.

Changing the preferences to only select by path only does not fix this behavior.

Is there any way to change this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its the **same** in CS6 as it is in CC. In fact, I think it's pretty much *always* been the same. Or at least since AI4 or 6.

If you have the **Attributes Panel** set to show the center point, it's then selectable.

[image]

If you don't want objects to be selected by their center point, select the object and turn off the center point display by clicking the button *without* the little dot on it.

<sub>Sidebar: The Attributes Panel is a great example of great Adobe UI decisions.... two buttons to simply toggle something on or off.</sub>

Comment: Thanks! It should be obvious that I am not that proficient in AI :) Do you know if it is possible to change the default behavior so I don't have to change it for each item? Haha, I think they should have 3 buttons to toggle it ;)